# Update if value conflicts with unique column ignore

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to update an user name's and nickname, Nickname is an unique column.

```
UPDATE `Users` 
SET `Nickname` = '$nickname', 
    `Name` = '$name' 
WHERE `ID` = '$userID'
```

If the user chooses a used nickname the query returns `Duplicate entry 'x' for key 'Nickname'` etc. Is it possible to make the query ignore duplicated columns and modify the other columns?

Comment: How about `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

Comment: I think that would work if I was inserting an user but I'm talking about doing an UPDATE. Maybe it's possible to do something like UPDATE A,B,C ON DUPLICATE UPDATE only A,B

Comment: Now I understand your question. I think a TRIGGER will be your better bet.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [REPLACE INTO](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html) instead

> REPLACE works exactly like INSERT, except that if an old row in the table has the same value as a new row for a PRIMARY KEY or a UNIQUE index, the old row is deleted before the new row is inserted.

Comment: I didn't know about REPLACE INTO, but from your description it seems that when a user tries a nickname if unavailable it would delete the user using it from the database.

Comment: It will delete the current row but will replace it with the same unique key with the updated values. A means of avoiding duplicate key constraint. "Keep in mind that a REPLACE INTO requires a test on the keys, and if a matching unique key is found on any or all columns, a DELETE FROM is executed, then an INSERT is executed."